# Do browsers merge form action querystring params with fields?

Tags: forms, dom, get

Consider this form:

```
<form method="GET" action="/signup?foo=1">
  <input type="hidden" name="bar" value="2"/>
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Will browsers reliably request "/signup?foo=1&bar=2"?

Answer (score 3):

## No.

JS Fiddle suggests Chrome will discard `foo=1`, and request `/signup?bar=2`.

[image]